# Are inherited non-final fields visible to other threads?

Tags: java, concurrency, visibility

Consider a third-party class like

```
class A {
    private int value;
    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

which I make immutable like

```
final class ImmutableA extends A {
    public ImmutableA(int value) {
        super.setValue(value);
    }
    public void setValue(int value) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

The [visibility guarantee for final fields](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html#17.5) doesn't apply here. My question is if other threads are guaranteed to see the correct state of `ImmutableA`.

If not, is there a solution? Using delegation is not an option since I need `ImmutableA` to be an `A`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `synchronized`, though this may slow down the getter:

```
final class ImmutableA extends A 
{
    public ImmutableA(int value) {
        synchronized (this) {
            super.setValue(value);
        }
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    public synchronized int getValue() {
        return super.getValue();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

yes, if you use `volatile` this has the guarantee that writes to it are visible to other threads

```
class A {
    private volatile int value;
    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned this more clearly: `A` is a third party class I can't modify.

Comment: another way it to add a synchronized block in the constructor but that is only half the solution, if you use external [happens-before](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility) guarantees then yes it will be visible

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by starblue's answer I've found a solution using no synchronization. It combines delegation with inheritance:

```
final class ImmutableA extends A {
    private final ImmutableA that;

    public ImmutableA(int value) {
        super.setValue(value);
        that = this;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    private int superGetValue() {
        return super.getValue();
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return that.superGetValue();
    }
}
```

I think it should work because of the `final` visibility guarantee. But I don't think it's worth the hassle. All methods need to be overridden and duplicated, since that.getValue() would lead to infinite recursion, and `that.super.getValue()` (or `super.that.getValue()`) is illegal.